# Querying OrientDB for latitude-longitude pairs in a circle of a given radius and center

Tags: orientdb

I have collection of nodes of latitude-longitude pairs.

How do I query [OrientDB](http://www.orientechnologies.com/orientdb/) to find all the nodes (latitude-longitude pairs) in a circle of given `radius` with center in given coordinates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need spatial index. See [orientdb-lucene plugin](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-lucene/wiki)

Alternatively (without spatial index, more slow) you can use `distance` function. It describes here: [SQL Where](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/SQL-Functions.html#distance)